# Select from SQL table WHERE clause is based on a list

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this part of code

```
$SIZES = "XS, S, M";  // this enumeration comes from a previous form submit that generates clothes sizes that are bigger or equal than 1
```

How could I use the variable above as the WHERE clause to select only the results bigger or equal than 1?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE $SIZES >= 1 ORDER BY ID ASC"; //my humble try
```

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: Here is my table structure

[image]

Comment: "bigger or equal than 1"... what's that 1?...

Comment: I would like to not display the results containing the value 0

Comment: 1 or bigger is the quantity value for each size (XS, S, M, etc)

Comment: Do you want to display products which have 1 or more of each of the sizes, or products that have 1 or more of any of the sizes?

Comment: @CAustin fixed.

Comment: So you want to have numbers and strings all in the same column? That's not actually possible with MySQL, so your `sizes` column is actually a `varchar` or something like that, right?

Comment: could you show the database structure?

Comment: @Nick 1 or more of each of the sizes

Comment: What is the name of the size column? and is there an `id` column?

Comment: @Nick I have 6 columns (XS, S, M, L, XL, XXL) with values of quantity for each of them. Yes, every product have an unique ID column

Comment: The $SIZES variable provides the result of filters selection coming from a submit form

Comment: This is open to a serious SQL injection, should you be getting values from user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select only products which have one or more of any of the sizes, you can use this query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE " . implode(' > 0 OR ', explode(',', $SIZES)) . " > 0
ORDER BY ID ASC";
```

For your sample `$SIZES` value, this gives `$sql` as

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE XS > 0 OR S > 0 OR M > 0
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

Comment: The first example doesnt work and I dont think the second one is suitable for my case. I updated the answer with the structure of my table.

Comment: @Adrian the second one is just the results of `echo $sql;`. What is wrong with the query - "doesn't work" is not useful in terms of understanding the problem? It seems to fit your table structure as described in the comments and in the picture in your question.

Comment: Sory, I'll try to get more details. Now seems it's work but if one of the size column (XS, S..) contains 0 the selection excludes the other results that have positive values.

Comment: @Adrian So, change `AND` to `OR` but another of your comments implied an `AND`

Comment: @tonypdmtr thank you. now it's perfect. Thank you Nick too, your piece of code is brilliant.

Comment: @Adrian I've updated the answer to allow selection of products which have one or more of *any* of the sizes (i.e. swapping `AND` for `OR`).

Comment: @Nick thank you so much, I really apreciated it!

Comment: @Adrian it's worth noting that you should take great care in how $SIZES is generated and checked, while sometimes necessary this kind of dynamic query generation cannot be parameterized so can be vulnerable to sql injection.